# lithium ion batteries in paralel

Tags: batteries, thermistor

I need to replace a 3.7V 1400mAh battery.  It has three leads the extra one being a thermal checker one I think.  I've tried hard to find the same one without success. It to fits into a small box 43mx30mmx20mm,  I can find larger mAh batteries but these dont fit.  So my idea is to put three 3,7V 900mAh batteries in parallel,  I want to use two lead batteries, If I connect the thermal check socket to the positive voltage will that be OK?   I read that these thermal leads are often superfluous/redundant and dont understand why the gadget I've got has to have the extra thermal lead.  Other gagets work with two leads and so why is the third thermal one needed?
I can buy two lead lithium batteries easily but the three lead ones are very rare and much more expensive.
Any advice on connecting the Lithium batteries in parallel is welcome.  I'd prefer not to have an explosion as they'll be mounted on my helmet!

Comment: If you don't know what you're doing, __do not__ use lithium-ion cells. They _can_ and _will_ __explode__ if you mistreat them.

Comment: Don't just connect them in parallel. If their voltages aren't exactly the same (they won't be), you'll have large currents, heat, and dead batteries.

Comment: Isn't a helmet designed to cushion large impacts?  W/ LiIons on your head, in the event that the safety features of the helmet are ever used, you are risking a fire with nasty gasses on a device strapped to your head.  Your failure modes are unacceptable.

Comment: ... at least move the batteries off your helmet, to give the burn surgeons less important tissue to work with.

Comment: Usually lithium batteries have protection circuits somewhere. Your existing battery probably does. These 900 mAh batteries, do they have built-in protection circuits? The purpose of the thermal sensor is to avoid charging the battery when it is too hot or too cold. Also, if the original space is for a 1.4 Ah battery, how is it that you have room for 3x0.9=2.7 Ah worth of cells? That seems suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend against 3 cells because your thermistor won't be touching 1 of the 3 cells. So I'd say only use two cells sandwiching the thermistor and learn how the thermistor is configured in your current battery. Try to mimic the configuration to make sure your device can read the battery temperature properly and doesn't think your battery is on fire or otherwise out of range (as mentioned above).

That said, if you are intent on putting any number of cells in parallel, you should use resistors to try to equalize the cell voltages before connecting (slow process and potentially hot resistors) or put the low cell on a battery charger until it is brought up to the same voltage as the other ones. Keep an eye on everything and measure with a voltmeter frequently. Be aware that after charging, the voltages make take a few minutes to stabilize. Once they're all pretty close you can safely connect them all, whatever voltage difference remains is going to be fixed as fast as the batteries can charge and discharge into each other... Scary with high power batteries that have significant voltage differences!!

The beautiful thing with paralleling battery cells is that as long as you're not draining them too fast, they'll act as one unit once they're connected initially and you don't have to worry about a weak cell blowing up due to overcharge/overdischarge.

Answer (score 0):

The handling of thermistor (third terminal in some Li-Ion batteries) is explained here, [pin connection in cell phone batteries](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/299788/117785) . The point is that if the thermistor pin is not handled properly, your device might think that the battery is overheated or out of range, and refuse to function.